# How can I force a virtual guest to use one of two NICs on the host?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, network-adapter

I have two in-built NICs - one wireless, one lan, on my Win10 host. I have a VirtualBoxed Win7 guest.

I have a custom proxy that uses localhost. I want to run the proxy on the Win7 guest and connect to that proxy from the Win10 host.

I'm wondering how I can force the Win7 guest to use one of my NICs and get separate IP, so I can connect to the proxy from my Win10 host.

I've tried modifying the interface metrics on the host so wireless takes priority (thus forcing the host to use the wireless NIC) and trying to set the Win7 adapter to bridged/ethernet NIC but it's not working - the interface metric for the wireless NIC just automatically jumps back above the ethernet card.

I may be barking up the wrong tree with what I need to accomplish so open to other methods - what I have is a .NET client that communicates with a server via protobufs. I have a custom proxy that will decode the protobufs being sent between the client and server. I have a ported Android version of the client, and when running the custom proxy on my host Win10, I can connect to it from my phone and the proxy will decode the protobufs sent from my phone and display on the host machine (where the proxy is running).

Ultimately, I need to be able to intercept the protobufs being sent from the .NET version of the client using my custom proxy.

Any help or advice appreciated.

Comment: Your question leaves me confused: 1. You want to run the proxy inside the win7 guest, but in next paragraph you change it to win10 host. 2. When choosing bridged adapter in Virtual Box, you must choose which NIC will it attach to - there shouldn't be problem with it using wrong one. 3. If you want Host to use only one NIC, then delete routes provided by the other one - your guest won't be using them anyway, since it's bridged.

Comment: Edited the phrasing to clarify, thanks. To clarify your answer, the bridged connection means that the guest will always be using the same NIC as the host? Is there another setting different from bridged I can use to force the guest to solely use a particular NIC? (the one my host is not using).

Comment: not exactly - the guest will always use the NIC, which you have manually choosen when selecting Bridged Adapter. On the other hand host will use the NIC, for which it has appropriate routes set - so if you don't want host to use wired NIC, you can just delete the routes. Guest doesn't need those to use the NIC.

Comment: add both nic's to the VM as *bridged* adapters, then set the one you DONT want used, as "not connected"  This will in effect be like "un-plugging" the cable to that nic.  This effects all users on that VM however, not just a specific user.

Comment: I have the host using wired NIC, which automatically takes priority over the wireless NIC so the wireless NIC should be free to use by the guest. When I have two adapters added to the VM and 'unplug' the wired NIC, the guest won't connect to the internet. Added images for clarity: http://imgur.com/a/1glvF

Comment: Try using openvpn server in windows 7 VM to route all traffic from win10 to win7. This covers all traffic, including your .net